# Launch long running cmd as pre-build event in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, cmd, gruntjs

I'm trying to launch a grunt process that will watch for .js file changes and transpile them into one file using grunt tasks.  I can run it manually all day long, but I want to make it a pre-build so when a new dev gets the solution, building will launch the watcher.  The problem (as you may have guessed) is that the grunt process stays running, so as a pre-build event, it never continues the build.  I thought that using `start` would be asynchronous and would launch it without VS waiting on it to complete to continue the build, but I was mistaken.  So, currently, my pre-build event is

`cmd /c start $(SolutionDir)ProjectName.Web\run-grunt.cmd $(SolutionDir)`

and run-grunt.cmd looks like

```
cd %1ProjectName.Web
grunt
```

This works but hangs until I close the cmd window which defeats the whole purpose.  So, two questions:

1. Is this the wrong way to get this watcher kicked off?
2. Is there a way to structure these such that VS will launch the cmd and then resume the build without waiting for a return?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your pre-build event to simply run a batch file that executes your current pre-build event?  It seems like it will work because the batch file that Visual Studio executes will actually complete, leaving another command window in its wake.

I tested my theory with two batch files:

**test1.bat**

```
call "cmd /C start test2.bat"
echo test1
```

**test2.bat**

```
echo test2
pause
```

If you're still needing some parts of the grunt task to execute pre-build, you can break them out into separate tasks, so your pre-build event may end up looking like this:

```
cd $(SolutionDir)ProjectName.Web\
grunt build
grunt-watch.bat
```

Comment: I've created a .bat file with `call "cmd /C start $(SolutionDir)Noteable.Web\LaunchGruntProcess.bat $(SolutionDir)"`.  LauchGruntProcess.bat has `cd %1Noteable.Web
start grunt`.  I end up with two windows and the build process still waits for completion.  =[

Comment: I tried with two .bat files in the process as well and oddly, the process in the original cmd window completes, but the build still hands.  Maybe if I don't use start...